# Converting Cartersian equation of a plane to parametric form in R3 when one or more variables are 0

Tags: linear-algebra

I have just learned how to convert a plane in R3 from Cartesian to parametric form, by setting 2 variables to 0 and solving for the 3rd one in order to obtain 3 points on the plane, and solve from there. However, this does not work when 1 or 2 of the variables are 0, as it is not possible to find 3 points on the plane in the same way (for example in the picture). How can this be solved for the particular question, and for other cases where there are variables that are 0? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: we have

$x_1=0+x_1$

$x_2=1 \quad +\frac{6}{5}x_3$

$x_3=0  \quad + x_3.$

Now put $t=x_1$ and $s=x_3.$ Then we derive:

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T=(0,1,0)^T+t(1,0,0)^T+s(0,\frac{6}{5},1)^T.$$

Answer (score 1):

First, I’d like to correct your terminology. When a variable doesn’t appear in the Cartesian equation, it’s not correct to say that “that variable is zero.” In fact, it can take any value at all. The *coefficient* of that variable in the equation, on the other hand, can be considered to be zero.

In the method that you describe, you are really computing the axis intercepts of the plane. Presumably, then, you choose one of the three points and use the other two to derive a pair of linearly-independent direction vectors for the plane.

When the Cartesian equation is “missing” a variable, the plane is parallel to the corresponding axis so there’s no axis intercept. In that case, however, any vector parallel to that axis is a direction vector of the plane. If there is only one “missing” variable, you can still use your method to find two points on the plane by setting the “missing” variable and one of the others to zero, then solving for the remaining variable. These two points will give you another direction vector for the plane.

So, in your example, $x_1$ doesn’t appear in the Cartesian equation, so $(1,0,0)$ is a direction vector. Setting $x_2$ and $x_3$ to zero in turn and solving for the other variable produces the points $(0,0,-5/6)$ and $(0,1,0)$, respectively, so you could take $(0,1,0)-(0,0,-5/6)=(0,1,5/6)$ as the second direction vector, yielding the parameterization $$(0,0,-5/6)+s(1,0,0)+t(0,1,5/6)$$ for this plane.

If two variables are missing from the Cartesian equation, you immediately know two direction vectors and can read a point on the plane directly from the equation.